Running Puppeteer within Miniflare (local Cloudflare worker simulator)
Is it possible to use @cloudflare/puppeteer for local development of Cloudflare workers?
What I tried so far
index.js (same as official example):
import puppeteer from "@cloudflare/puppeteer";

export default {
    async fetch(request, env, ctx) {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch(env.MYBROWSER);
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.goto("https://example.com");
        const metrics = await page.metrics();
        await browser.close();
        return Response.json(metrics);  
    },
};

wrangler.toml:
#:schema node_modules/wrangler/config-schema.json
name = "my-first-worker"
main = "src/index.js"
compatibility_date = "2024-04-05"
compatibility_flags = ["nodejs_compat"]

browser = { binding = "MYBROWSER" }

Running this with wrangler dev and then calling the worker throws the following error:
[wrangler:err] TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'fetch')
    at PuppeteerWorkers.launch (file:///home/duranda/my-first-worker/node_modules/@cloudflare/puppeteer/src/puppeteer-core.ts:107:32)
    at Object.fetch (file:///home/duranda/my-first-worker/src/index.js:15:35)
    at fetchDispatcher (file:///home/duranda/my-first-worker/.wrangler/tmp/bundle-3eSyZw/middleware-loader.entry.ts:56:17)
    at __facade_invokeChain__ (file:///home/duranda/my-first-worker/node_modules/wrangler/templates/middleware/common.ts:53:9)
    at Object.next (file:///home/duranda/my-first-worker/node_modules/wrangler/templates/middleware/common.ts:50:11)
    at jsonError (file:///home/duranda/my-first-worker/node_modules/wrangler/templates/middleware/middleware-miniflare3-json-error.ts:22:30)
    at __facade_invokeChain__ (file:///home/duranda/my-first-worker/node_modules/wrangler/templates/middleware/common.ts:53:9)
    at Object.next (file:///home/duranda/my-first-worker/node_modules/wrangler/templates/middleware/common.ts:50:11)
    at drainBody (file:///home/duranda/my-first-worker/node_modules/wrangler/templates/middleware/middleware-ensure-req-body-drained.ts:5:30)
    at __facade_invokeChain__ (file:///home/duranda/my-first-worker/node_modules/wrangler/templates/middleware/common.ts:53:9)


If you want to run it for the testing purseses just press 'l' from the console and turn off the local mode. it will work.

So Puppeteer only works remotely with Cloudflare workers?

I get this same error, even when running with --remote flag

Their docs say that Browser Rendering is not supported in Local Mode and, hence, --remote option is required 
